# Printing String after the user input on the same line

Tags: python, input

so basically i want to use the python input() function to get a velocity input from the user. After the user types the number i want to display a nit like m/s behind the user input.
I thought i can do something like this:

```
velocity = input("Please enter a velocity: ", end='')
print("m/s")
```

but end='' only works with print() and not with input(). Do you have any other ideas?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already reading the user input into a variable called `velocity`. So you already have the value, you just need to print it and append `m/s` to it.

Here's a way to do it -

```
velocity = input("Please enter a velocity: ")
print(velocity, end="m/s\n")
```

`\n` is newline character and is adding a newline after `m/s`
Here's a test run -

```
~ python my_test.py
Please enter a velocity: 67
67m/s
```

For printing you can use different versions -

```
print(f"{velocity}m/s")
print("{}m/s".format(velocity))
```

---

Based on comments, the OP wants the input field itself to be updated with that value. This behaviour is not supported by the `input()` function by default, and would involve terminal text manipulation.

You can use [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html#user-input) to manipulate the strings.

---

If you only want to update the **previous line** once the user has given input, you can use the [ANSI escape code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) for going to previous line(`\033[F`) -

```
velocity = input("Please enter a velocity: ")
print(f"\033[FPlease enter a velocity: {velocity}m/s")
```

Try running above code, after you press enter, the previous line would be replaced and m/s would be appended to the original input.

Sample run, while entering the value -

```
~ python my_test.py
Please enter a velocity: 67
```

after you press Enter, the previous line is updated in place -

```
~ python my_test.py
Please enter a velocity: 67m/s
```

Comment: Yes, i thought so, but is there a possibility the output looks like this:
```
Please enter a velocity: 67 m/s
```

Comment: So if a user inputs 6, in realtime, you want the line shown in terminal to 6 m/s, when he enters 7 after, you want the line to be updated to 67 m/s?

Comment: update the line after the user input, if that is possible.

Comment: @MalteRothkamm Try running the last code snippet in updated answer.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do it is, to take the input in the print method.
i.e

```
print(input("Please enter a velocity: "), "m/s")
```

OutPut

```
Please enter a velocity: 64
64 m/s
```